# Validating against dynamic data - JSON Schema - Ajv

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema, ajv

I'm trying to create a JSON Schema for something very dynamic. Say I have two pieces of data, and I want one (the source) to determine the validity of the other (the target). Both can change over time, but both will always be an array of objects with known properties. For example:

**source.json**

```json
[
    { "id": 23, "active": true },
    { "id": 9, "active": false },
    { "id": 6, "active": true }
]
```

**target.json**

```json
[
    { "identifier": 6 }
]
```

The schema I'm trying to create is this: For each *active* object in the source array, there should be an equivalent object in the target array. A little more formally, given an object in the source array where "active" equals true and "id" equals **x**, there should be an object in the target array where "identifier" equals **x**.

In the example above, the target would be invalid because it's missing an object like `{ "identifier": 23 }`.

However, I want to statically define this schema (or something capable of generating it) in a JSON file ahead of time, and this feels pretty tough since the source array can change. I'm using Ajv, and I'm aware that it supports the `$data` reference, but I'm not sure that's enough to help me here. The other option I could see is creating some kind of schema-generator definition? In concept, it too would be a JSON object I define ahead of time, but at runtime it would be used to safely generate arbitrary schemas based on runtime data such as the source array. However, if a mechanism like this doesn't already exist, trying to implement it myself sounds like a great way to give myself a code-injection vulnerability.

Thanks for your time!